# No se inicia la aplicacion en android studio : unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider

Tags: android-studio, firebase, app

Buenas tardes cada vez que intento iniciar un proyecto me sale el siguiente error:

`banner keeps stopping`

Pero no entiendo porque. Entonces si me podrían ayudar porque me sale ese error de no poder  abrir la app en android studio. Ya que siempre me sale el mismo error de la aplicación estoy utilizando un google ads con FireBase y quiero resolver ese problema .Gracias.

estaba utilizando normalmente la app pero de pronto se me comenzo a aparecer ese error lo intento solucionar pero no encuentro como .

He estado intentando resolver esto desde hace mucho tiempo .

aqui esta el logcat

2020-06-21 11:00:23.044 5363-5363/app.ejempl.original I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-06-21 11:00:23.052 5363-5363/app.ejempl.original W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-06-21 11:00:23.731 5363-5363/app.ejempl.original W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.ejempl.original-2/lib/x86
2020-06-21 11:00:23.929 5363-5363/app.ejempl.original D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-06-21 11:00:23.933 5363-5363/app.ejempl.original E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.ejempl.original, PID: 5363
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyc.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:24)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.1.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        ... 10 more
```

> Activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="app.ejemplo.banner.MainActivity">


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.914"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.ejemplo.banner">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

> MainActivity

```
package app.ejemplo.banner;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private AdView mAdView;

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

   }
}
```

> Build.Gradle project

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
     }
      dependencies {
      classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
     // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
  }

    allprojects {
     repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Build.Gradle app

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.ejemplo.banner"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"

     testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema se describe aquì:

> Unable to get provider
> com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider:

para resolverlo tienes que agregar la definiciòn de tu App ID definida para los anuncios dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` que es lo que indica el mensaje:

```
<manifest>
   <application>
      
      ...
      ...
      ...

      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
          android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```